# About directshow: Why can't I release it thoroughly?

Tags: visual-c++, memory-management, com, directshow

Everytime I load a new movie and then close it, I find that the used memory of my programme increases by 20-50M. I has tried many ways to release it, but none of them works. ( I even used CoUninitialize(); )

Here's the main part of the code.

```
// DirectShow interfaces
IGraphBuilder *pGB = NULL;
IMediaControl *pMC = NULL;
IMediaEventEx *pME = NULL;
IBasicAudio *pBA = NULL;
IMediaSeeking *pMS = NULL;
IMediaPosition *pMP = NULL;
// VMR9 interfaces
IVMRWindowlessControl9 *pWC = NULL;

#define JIF(x) if (FAILED(hr=(x))) \
{Msg(TEXT("FAILED(hr=0x%x) in ") TEXT(#x) TEXT("\n\0"), hr); return hr; }

HRESULT PlayMovieInWindow(LPTSTR szFile)
{
HRESULT hr;
// hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
// Get the interface for DirectShow's GraphBuilder
JIF(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    IID_IGraphBuilder, (void **)&pGB));

if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    IBaseFilter *pVmr;

    // Create the VMR and add it to the filter graph.
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_VideoMixingRenderer9, NULL,
        CLSCTX_INPROC, IID_IBaseFilter, (void**)&pVmr);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pGB->AddFilter(pVmr, L"Video Mixing Renderer 9");

        //Add LAV Filters to filter graph
        IBaseFilter *pLavSplitterSource, *pLavVideoDecoder, *pLavAudioDecoder, *pAudioRender;
        IFileSourceFilter *pFileSourceFilter;

        hr = AddFilterByCLSID(pGB, CLSID_LavSplitter_Source, &pLavSplitterSource, L"Lav Splitter Source");
        hr = pLavSplitterSource->QueryInterface(IID_IFileSourceFilter, (void **)&pFileSourceFilter);
        hr = pFileSourceFilter->Load(szFile, NULL);

        hr = AddFilterByCLSID(pGB, CLSID_LavVideoDecoder, &pLavVideoDecoder, L"Lav Video Decoder");
        hr = AddFilterByCLSID(pGB, CLSID_LavAudioDecoder, &pLavAudioDecoder, L"Lav Audio Decoder");
        hr = AddFilterByCLSID(pGB, CLSID_DSoundRender, &pAudioRender, L"DirectSound Audio render");

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            // Set the rendering mode and number of streams
            IVMRFilterConfig9 *pConfig;

            JIF(pVmr->QueryInterface(IID_IVMRFilterConfig9, (void**)&pConfig));
            JIF(pConfig->SetRenderingMode(VMR9Mode_Windowless));

            hr = pVmr->QueryInterface(IID_IVMRWindowlessControl9, (void**)&pWC);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                JIF(pWC->SetVideoClippingWindow(hVideo));
                JIF(pWC->SetBorderColor(RGB(0, 0, 0)));
            }
            SAFE_RELEASE(pConfig);
            SAFE_RELEASE(pVmr);
        }
    }

    // Render the file programmatically to use the VMR9 as renderer.
    // Pass TRUE to create an audio renderer also.
    if (FAILED(hr = RenderFileToVideoRenderer(pGB, szFile, FALSE))) return hr;

    // QueryInterface for DirectShow interfaces
    JIF(pGB->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaControl, (void **)&pMC));
    JIF(pGB->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaEventEx, (void **)&pME));
    JIF(pGB->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaSeeking, (void **)&pMS));
    JIF(pGB->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaPosition, (void **)&pMP));
    JIF(pGB->QueryInterface(IID_IBasicAudio, (void **)&pBA));

    // Have the graph signal event via window callbacks for performance
    JIF(pME->SetNotifyWindow((OAHWND)hVideo, WM_GRAPHNOTIFY, 0));

    JIF(pMC->Run());
}
return hr;
}

void CloseInterfaces(void)
{
HRESULT hr;
// Stop media playback
if (pMC)
    hr = pMC->Stop();

// Disable event callbacks
if (pME)
    hr = pME->SetNotifyWindow((OAHWND)NULL, 0, 0);

// Enumerate the filters And remove them
IEnumFilters *pEnum = NULL;
hr = pGB->EnumFilters(&pEnum);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    IBaseFilter *pFilter = NULL;
    while (S_OK == pEnum->Next(1, &pFilter, NULL))
    {
        // Remove the filter.
        pGB->RemoveFilter(pFilter);
        // Reset the enumerator.
        pEnum->Reset();
        pFilter->Release();
    }
    pEnum->Release();
}

// Release and zero DirectShow interfaces
SAFE_RELEASE(pME);
SAFE_RELEASE(pMS);
SAFE_RELEASE(pMP);
SAFE_RELEASE(pMC);
SAFE_RELEASE(pBA);
SAFE_RELEASE(pWC);
SAFE_RELEASE(pGB);
// CoUninitialize();
}
```

I use LAV Filters as the decoder. Platform: win7 vs2013

This question has bothered me for more than a week. I will appreciate it very much if you solve my problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `1` using raw interface pointers it is easy to leak a reference, apparently you only posted a fragments, so leaks can be anywhere - in particular, even in your code snippet variables under line "Add LAV Filters to filter graph" are not released properly, or this code is not shown `2` there is no proof that you are reliably measuring memory leak/increased consumption `3` after all, 1+ of the filters participating in the topology might be leaky.

Comment: In CloseInterfaces() I enumerate those LAV filters and remove them, and I have tried SAFE_RELEASE them after adding them to the filter graph, it doesn't work any way. I don't think a 50M-increase in memory can't be a leak caused by Directshow. After I play a few movies, the used memory can be 300M or higher.

Comment: `pLavSplitterSource` and `pFileSourceFilter` are never released in the code you show. _In CloseInterfaces() I enumerate those LAV filters and remove them_ - You only release referenced which you have acquired by enumerating them.

Comment: Even I do these `SAFE_RELEASE(pAudioRender);`
`SAFE_RELEASE(pLavAudioDecoder);`
`SAFE_RELEASE(pLavVideoDecoder);`
`SAFE_RELEASE(pFileSourceFilter);`
`SAFE_RELEASE(pLavSplitterSource);` In CloseInterface(), it doesn't work